# iOS8 custom keyboard can change theme on simulator but can't on the Real machine

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults

I'm working on iOS8 custom keyboard, I want to change the keyboard's backgroung in this way:

1. Set `RequestsOpenAccess = YES;`
2. Settings:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults * usrInfo = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myKeyboard"];
   [usrInfo setObject:theme.icon forKey:@"themeName"]; // This is the new data;

   [usrInfo synchronize];
   ```
3. keyboardChange:

   ```
   NSUserDefaults * usrInfo = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"myKeyboard"];
   [usrInfo synchronize];

   NSString * str = [usrInfo objectForKey:@"themeName"];
   ```

Then I can change the theme of the keyboard, it's ok on the simulator. But when I used the real machine, everything is ok but I can never change the theme, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. It is because the iOS8 on my iPhone is beta version, after updating the system to the official version, the problem is no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in your device is it set to allow full access?

Comment: Thanks for your help.Finally I solved the problem. It is because the iOS8 on my iPhone is beta version, after updating the system to the official version, the problem is no longer exist.